# Cisco C3064PQ advertise 600x /32 Routes

Tags: cisco

i have a pair of nexus 3064pq in a vpc mode and i want to add 600x /32 network in my advertisement under router bgp XXX , so i want to know if there is no problem with this and it does not cause performance degree ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will work fine.

Are these routes coming from static or another routing protocol?  If so, it might be better to use routing policy to match the routes (e.g. by tag, interface, or originating protocol) instead of list hundreds of routes.